# Are Views in Domino Thread Safe?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

As I understand it, if I open a view from a database using db.getView() there's no point in doing this multiple times from different threads.

But suppose I have multiple threads searching the View using getAllDocumentsByKey()  Is it safe to do so and iterate over the DocumentCollections in parallel?

Also, Document.recycle() messes with the DocumentCollection, will this mess with each other if two threads search for the same value and have the same results in their collection?

Note: I'm just starting to research this in depth, but thought it'd be a good thing to have documented here, and maybe I'll get lucky and someone will have the answer.

Comment: Are you asking about the Java classes or the COM classes?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear on that.  I'm talking about the JAVA API

Comment: The Java API synchronizes operations, but is susceptible to issues when your code changes the state of C API objects that correspond to database objects and are shared between Java objects across threads.  I think you'll be safe with the getAllDocumentsByKey operations, but given the synchonization that occurs behind the scenes I doubt you'll get much advantage from multithreading it this way.  I would probably just have one thread doing the searches and dispatching the collections to worker threads.

Answer (score 3):

The Domino Java API doesn't really like sharing objects across threads. If you recycle() one  view in one thread, it will delete the backend JNI references for all objects that referenced that view.

So you will find your other threads are then broken.

Bob Balaban did a really good series of articles on how the Java API works and recycling. Here is a link to part of it.

http://www.bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/geek-o-terica-5-taking-out-the-garbage-java?opendocument&comments

Answer (score 2):

Each thread will have its own copy of a `DocumentCollection` object returned by the `getAllDocumentsByKey()` method, so there won't be any threading issues.  The `recycle()` method will free up memory on your object, not the Document itself, so again there wouldn't be any threading issues either.

Probably the most likely issue you'll have is if you delete a document in the collection in one thread, and then later try to access the document in another.  You'll get a "document has been deleted" error.  You'll have to prepare for those types of errors and handle them gracefully.